# Is there a reason why no one combines word embeddings with the median?

Tags: natural-language-processing, word-embedding

Could you combine word embeddings with the median per dimension to get a document embedding? In my case I have a huge amount of words to build one document, which in turn should describe a topic. I feel like using the median is the right thing to do, as I get the most common parameter value per dimension. However, I cannot find anyone trying it before. This is why I'm wondering, is there something speaking against it?

Comment: What do you mean by "combine word embeddings with the median"? Median of a sequence? Which sequence? How how do you want to combine "word embeddings" with the "median". I don't understand this question maybe because I'm misinterpreting the word "median".

Comment: I think @Stephan means combining a number of embeddings into one by computing the median per dimension. I remember reading a paper that showed mean generally works best, but I can't find it now. In any case, median *may* work well because you can think of each embedding dimension as a distribution. If the distribution is skewed, the median will have a higher posterior density than the mean, but intuitively these dimensions would be approximately normal so the mean and median would be similar. Try it out!